# FrameLayout not displaying elements

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a *FrameLayout* that contains other *FrameLayouts*. I have created an EditorView class that extends FrameLayout, and I want it to display *FileView*, another class that extends *FrameLayout*. But in Android Studio preview I get an blank view. What am I doing wrong.

This is the ediorview_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/html1" />

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/html2" />

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/html3" />

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/html4" />

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/html5" />

    <com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView
        android:id="@+id/html7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/html6" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is lineview_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lineNumber"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/typeyourline"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="32dp"
        android:textColorHint="#546E7A" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is EditorView class:

```
public class EditorView extends FrameLayout {

    private Context mContext;
    private AttributeSet mAttributeSet;

    public EditorView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mAttributeSet = attrs;
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.editor_start_html_layout, this);
        LineView line1 = view.findViewById(R.id.html1);
        LineView line2 = view.findViewById(R.id.html2);
        LineView line3 = view.findViewById(R.id.html3);
        LineView line4 = view.findViewById(R.id.html4);
        LineView line5 = view.findViewById(R.id.html5);
        LineView line6 = view.findViewById(R.id.html6);
        LineView line7 = view.findViewById(R.id.html7);
        line1.setLineNumber(1);
        line1.setLineContents("<html>");
        line2.setLineNumber(2);
        line2.setLineContents("<head>");
        line3.setLineNumber(3);
        line3.setLineContents("    <title></title>");
        line4.setLineNumber(4);
        line4.setLineContents("</head>");
        line5.setLineNumber(5);
        line5.setLineContents("<body>");
        line6.setLineNumber(6);
        line6.setLineContents("</body>");
        line7.setLineNumber(7);
        line7.setLineContents("</html>");
    }
}
```

And In preview I get this:
[image]

Comment: Where do you add FrameLayout? I can't see any

Comment: It's my class that extends FrameLayout. In XML it is called com.itsvaske.webio.Views.LineView.

Comment: So LiveView contains multiple FramLayout inside it?

Comment: No, EditorView contains multiple LineViews. And LineView is an FrameLayout.